# Почему $_POST всегда существет?

Tags: php

Проверяю в коде php, задан ли `$_POST` через `isset($_POST)`

Заметил, что выражение всегда возвращает `true`, даже когда никаких данных не передовали, при этом $_POST является пустым массивом. Почему так происходит и зачем так сделано? Или это только при определенных условиях?

Вопрос чисто теоретический, проблемы тут никакой нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_POST`, как и другие суперглобальные переменные (встроенные переменные всегда доступные во всех областях видимости) PHP (`$GLOBALS`, `$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, `$_FILES`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SESSION`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_ENV`), изначально инициализируется пустым массивом, а потом заполняется соответствующими значениями.

За исключением `$_SESSION`, которую нужно явно инициализировать вызовом `session_start()`.

Сделано так, скорее всего, по каким-то внутренним соображениям для удобства.

Так же, так как в большинстве случаев в получении всего содержимого суперглобальной переменной нет необходимости, а нужно лишь получить значение или проверить наличие определенного ключа, и зная что переменная всегда массив, удобно использовать конструкцию `isset($_VAR[$key]);` без дополнительных проверок самой переменной.

Comment: "встроенные переменные всегда доступные во всех областях видимости" видимо в этом и ответ, чтобы переменная всегда была доступна, она всегда должна существовать)))